# Login button facebook android doesn't redirect to new activity

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

When i run my Android app, and click approve to the give permissions it not get redirected to the MainActivity. The "Logged in" message doesn't shows up in the Catlog.  I have read the Facebook developers guide, and compared my code to different topics here at Stack. I can't see i have done anything wrong.

I would be very glad for help.

```
public class Login extends Activity {

/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */

     private CallbackManager callbackManager;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    final CallbackManager callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile", "email", "user_friends");


    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {


        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            System.out.print("Logged in");

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code
            Log.i("Error" , "Error");
            }


        });
    }

  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  }

}
```

StackTrace

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result   ResultInfo{who=null, request=64206, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to   activity {org.MYapp.FBtestApp/org.MYapp.FBtestApp.Login}:   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean   com.facebook.CallbackManager.onActivityResult(int, int, android.content.Intent)'   on a null object reference
          at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3974)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4017)

 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean com.facebook.CallbackManager.onActivityResult(int, int, android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference
        at org.MYapp.FBtestApp.Login.onActivityResult(Login.java:98)
```

Comment: It's quite hard to help you out when you're only providing code. Are there any errors in the logcat? Are there parameters that are null (especially "resultCode" and "data")?

Comment: I encourage you to *not* update your code once you've asked the question. The accepted answer now no longer makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the login to work, you have to remove the `onActivityResult()` method from inside the `FacebookCallback` anomymous class.
The correct code should look like this:

```
private CallbackManager callbackManager;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile", "email", "user_friends");

    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            System.out.print("Logged in");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code
            Log.i("Error" , "Error");
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: Error: Can not resolve symbol callbackManager
           callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
       }

EDIT: Missed your update in top

Comment: Create a CallbackManager member variable. Look at my code, I have edited it (1st and 9th line).

Comment: You missed a bit at my code. Change the line: final CallbackManager callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create(); to: callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create(); Also don't forget super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); in onActivityResult().

Answer (score 3):

First of all, insert private `private CallbackManager callbackManager;`
into your code. It should look something like this:

```
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
```

Then add `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());`

before `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

Try this Hope this works

Comment: I didn't expect that this will work, I don't understand why this worked after moving before `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

Added:

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
```

Before:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

It was strange, for everything was working fine earlier; but suddenly, I had this issue. Now, it's fixed with the aforementioned solution.