# Android Facebook-SDK: Class not found when unmarshalling: com.facebook.login.LoginClient$Request

Tags: android, facebook

Did anyone saw this before?

Here is a [releated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30513626/error-class-not-found-when-unmarshalling-com-facebook-login-login-client-reque), but our stacktrace is different, for me it's purely on Facebook-SDK.

There been a [bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1621984714705591/) to Facebook on this manner, it's closed now. They suggest to add those lines:

```
getActivity().getIntent().setExtrasClassLoader(LoginClient.Request.class.getClassLoader());

request = (LoginClient.Request) getActivity().getIntent().getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_REQUEST);
```

But I don't understand where to add this. Also `LoginClient` is package local.

```
09-24 08:28:56.658    4107-4145/? E/Parcel﹕ Class not found when unmarshalling: com.facebook.login.LoginClient$Request
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.facebook.login.LoginClient$Request
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:308)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:272)
            at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2275)
            at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2239)
            at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2146)
            at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2479)
            at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
            at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:918)
            at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:5378)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1772)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1317)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:4610)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:4453)
            at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:140)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3001)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.login.LoginClient$Request" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:308)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:272)
            at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2275)
            at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2239)
            at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2146)
            at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2479)
            at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
            at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:918)
            at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:5378)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1772)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1317)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:4610)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:4453)
            at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:140)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3001)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.facebook.login.LoginClient$Request
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 18 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have figured this out yet, but here's the answer (that worked for me).

I was using the login button from a fragment (since the old SDK). But you can't use it this way anymore. You have to use that button from an activity, not from a fragment.

I think that's also your problem, since you're using "getActivity()."

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

I confirmed (according to the findings in the bug report) that an LG with a fresh factory reset, update and FB app install from Facebook did the right thing with the exact same APK that fails on my Samsung A7. This appears to be a problem with the FB SDK and Samsung devices.

Answer (score 0):

Guys my problem is solve just overriding

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

Comment: please add some details related your solution

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and I fixed with multidex enabled

add this in your build file

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

also this code in your activity

```
@Override   
protected void attachBaseContext(Context context) {
         super.attachBaseContext(context);
         MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

after adding this in your build gradle dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```